# Controlling OBS with midipipe with applescript and novation launchpad

Tags: applescript

I am using applescript in midipipe application to run the scripts below, so that my novation launchpad can be mapped to hotkeys in OBS:

Code is:

```
on runme(message)
#Pad 1
#11,11, CTRLZ
if (item 2 of message = 11)
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "z" using control down
end tell
end if

#Pad 2
#12,12, CTRLX
if (item 2 of message = 12)
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "x" using control down
end tell
end if

#Pad 3
#13,13, CTRLY
if (item 2 of message = 13)
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "y" using control down
end tell
end if

#Pad 4
#14,14, CTRLE
if (item 2 of message = 14)
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "e" using control down
end tell
end if
end runme
```

BUT

as soon as i had another pad it "contains errors" when compiling, i'm unable to see what the error actually is and the code for pad 5 is the same as the rest of the other parts.

```
on runme(message)
#Pad 1
#11,11, CTRLZ
if (item 2 of message = 11)
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "z" using control down
end tell
end if

#Pad 2
#12,12, CTRLX
if (item 2 of message = 12)
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "x" using control down
end tell
end if

#Pad 3
#13,13, CTRLY
if (item 2 of message = 13)
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "y" using control down
end tell
end if

#Pad 4
#14,14, CTRLE
if (item 2 of message = 14)
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "e" using control down
end tell
end if

#Pad 5
#19.19, CTRLS
if (item 2 of message = 19)
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke “s" using control down
end tell
end if
end runme
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

after `on runme(message)` append:

```
tell application "OBS"
    activate
end tell
```